# Списало 10 репутации

Tags: поддержка, репутация

Еще сегодня утром у меня было 82 репутации и  мог назначать награду. Спустя пару часов, у меня ее 72, ничего не списывало, хотя на картинке видно, что я получил возможность (награду) жертвовать своей небольшой репутацией. Что случилось?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Один из ваших ответов преобразовали в комментарий, плюс на нем откатился.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На странице с репутацией внизу есть флажок <kbd>показать удалённые сообщения</kbd>. Если его отметить, то можно увидеть -10 за удалённый ответ (на самом деле [он](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/890249/178988) был преобразован в комментарий).